# Deleting Diagonals from a mesh automatically?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I downloaded a low-poly gun model ".obj" online. When Imported, I discovered that the author has added weird diagonals on each face of the mesh.

[image]

I can remove them one-by-one but it will take whole day to do!

**Is there any modifier to solve this?**

Comment: Those are called edges and they are most likely the result of something like triangulating so Triangulate modifier won't change much. This is destructive change of the mesh geometry and there is little you can do to fix that automatically; the only way would be to select all and press Alt+J to convert tris to quads. It won't work ideally and equally for all the mesh. The flexible ways include retopologizing the mesh, i.e constructing one more with snapping on top of this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for limited dissolve! All you have to do is select your mesh in edit mode and search for it in the space search bar.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not know of any modifier that removes diagonal lines from the mesh. You could, however delete each line manually. Or, you could use the triangulate modifier that basically adds more of those lines.

I may be wrong, but my best advice would be to manually delete the lines in the mesh, or download a different mesh.

Sorry

Comment: Deleting each line with hands... It gonna be headache. anyway thanks for super-instant reply :)